# how to change the default selection from first item in the array to the last item?

Tags: android, arrays, android-layout, spinner, android-resources

What I have is a spinner which if filled from values a string array, all in xml. 
What I want is to change the default selection from first item in the array to the last item. Is it possible to do so?
I've been searching a lot for this but all I found is how to do it programmaticaly or how to change the text appeared on the spinner before user selection. Which are not what I look for.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Did you try `yourSpinner.setSelection(yourArray.length - 1)`?

Comment: What's the problem in doing it programmatically ??

Comment: @Rohit : yes I know about it. Just wanted to see whether or not I can do it in xml.

Comment: @vivek : I have plenty of spinners and it was ideal for me if I could do this in xml. Which is apparently not possible.

Comment: @Tina I don't think that is possible but you could do something little different. set `android:spinnerMode="dialog"` and the use `android:prompt="Gender"`. This way you could have a default spinner text from xml.

Answer (score 1):

spinner.setSelection(pass here index number which data you want to show);

like:-

```
spinner.setSelection(your_Array_List.size()-1);
```

Comment: No, I was looking for an attribute or sth in xml.